# Обновление переменных в шаблонных строках

Tags: javascript, строки

Итак, есть у меня массив строк:

```
const VEGETABLE_MESSAGE = [
  `Clean vegetable garden: ${VEGETABLE_GARDEN.building}%`,
  `Seeds planted: ${VEGETABLE_GARDEN.seedPlant} seeds`,
  `Collect the harvest: ${VEGETABLE_GARDEN.harvesting} %`,
  '<span style="color:red">You forgot to water the seeds, the entire harvest was lost!</span>',
  '<span style="color:red">Water seeds: no</span>',
  '<span style="color:green">Water seeds: yes</span>',
];
```

есть вывод необходимой строки:

```
let VEGETABLE_GARDEN = {
building: 0,}
const VG = VEGETABLE_GARDEN

function mes() {
if (VG.building < 100) {
    mesID = 0
  } else if (VG.seedPlant < 100) {
    mesID = 1
  } else if (VG.harvestDay == 0) {
    mesID = 2
  } else if (VG.seedDie == 1) {
    mesID = 3
  } else {
    mesID = waterMesVG();
  }

document.getElementById('massageVG').innerHTML = VEGETABLE_MESSAGE[mesID];
}
mes() // итог будет: `Clean vegetable garden: 0 %`
// далее я выполняю некоторые действия и значение VEGETABLE_GARDEN.building меняется, например:
VEGETABLE_GARDEN.building = 15
// но при повтором вызове mes()
mes() // итог будет все равно `Clean vegetable garden: 0 %` вместо `Clean vegetable garden: 15 %`. Это и есть моя проблема. 
// если же поместить VEGETABLE_MESSAGE в mes() то все будет прекрасно работать, однако это неудобно в силу ниже описанных проблем. Поэтому мне нужно, чтобы VEGETABLE_MESSAGE оставался за пределами исполняемой функции.
```

И вот значит какая проблема: если я обьявляю массив `VEGETABLE_MESSAGE` внутри функции публикации строки, то переменная `${VEGETABLE_GARDEN.building}` и другие подобные переменные без проблем обновляются и публикуются как надо, но стоит мне вынести этот массив за пределы функции, обновления прекращаются.

Как я понимаю, проблема в том, что эти функции считывают значение переменных лишь при первом запуске и все. Итак, вопрос, как можно заставить переменные в таких строках обновляться за пределами вызываемой функции, например, при изменении значения самой переменной? Просто у меня такого текста довольно много и мне хотелось бы собрать его в одном месте, чтобы не лазить по всему коду в случае, например, если его нужно будет перевести на другой язык. Буду признателен за помощь и разьяснение того, как можно справиться с подобной проблемой.

Comment: Если честно не совсем понятна проблема. Что значит "обновляются" и что значит "публикуются"? Как именно происходит это "обновление" и "публикация"? И **зачем** они обновляются, если это КОНСТАНТА? ...... Нужен нормальный **воспроизводимый** кусок кода. Что и где происходит и какой результат ожидается

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, немного переделал код, чтобы показать свою проблему. Надеюсь, так Вам станет понятнее, чего я пытаюсь добиться. И КОНСТАНТА массив сообщений, а не сами переменные.

Comment: `if (VG.building < 100) {`․․․ Что за переменная - `VG`?  Где оно объявлено? И что оно хранит?

Comment: [У меня IDE светится](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqEeN.png), когда я пытаюсь разбирать ваш код, понимаете? Я никак не могу понять, что за переменные, что за функции, что из них получается, что должно получится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В очередной раз убедился, что правильно поставленный вопрос много чего значит. Я прицепился к тому, что работаю с шаблонными строками, но по факту мне нужно было лишь настроить обновление переменной, если ее значение менялось, при публикации указанной строки.

Таким образом, я нашел следующее решение данной проблемы: Я просто вынес все переменные за пределы строки и вернул их в функцию, а в строках добавил хтмл-элемент `<span>` с уникальным id. Далее, при публикации нужной строки, внутри функции я просто записывал текущее значение в указанный `<span>`:

```
/*
------------- Вот так было -----------------------
const VEGETABLE_MESSAGE = [
  `Clean vegetable garden: ${VEGETABLE_GARDEN.building}%`,
  `Seeds planted: ${VEGETABLE_GARDEN.seedPlant} seeds`,
  `Collect the harvest: ${VEGETABLE_GARDEN.harvesting} %`,
  '<span style="color:red">You forgot to water the seeds, the entire harvest was lost!</span>',
  '<span style="color:red">Water seeds: no</span>',
  '<span style="color:green">Water seeds: yes</span>',
];
-------------- Вот так стало -----------------------------
*/
const VEGETABLE_MESSAGE = [
  'Clean vegetable garden: <span id="span_VG" style="color:red"></span>%',
  'Seeds planted: <span id="span_VG" style="color:red"></span> seeds',
  'Collect the harvest: <span id="span_VG" style="color:red"></span> %',
  '<span style="color:red">You forgot to water the seeds, the entire harvest was lost!</span>',
  '<span style="color:red">Water seeds: no</span>',
  '<span style="color:green">Water seeds: yes</span>',
];
let VEGETABLE_GARDEN = {
building: 0,}
let x; 
const VG = VEGETABLE_GARDEN

function mes() {
if (VG.building < 100) {
    mesID = 0
    x = VG.building // здесь присваиваем обновленное значение
  } else if (VG.seedPlant < 100) {
    mesID = 1
  } else if (VG.harvestDay == 0) {
    mesID = 2
  } else if (VG.seedDie == 1) {
    mesID = 3
  } else {
    mesID = waterMesVG();
  }

document.getElementById('massageVG').innerHTML = VEGETABLE_MESSAGE[mesID];
if (x != null) { // если переменная не пустая, публикуем ее.
    document.getElementById('span_VG').innerHTML = x;
  }
}
VEGETABLE_GARDEN.building = 0
mes() // Clean vegetable garden: 0%
VEGETABLE_GARDEN.building = 15
mes() // Clean vegetable garden: 15%
```

Answer (score 1):

Шаблонная строка это безымянная функция, которая вызывается в момент объявления, вычисляется и результат вычисления подставляется на место самой строки. В вашем случае все строки будут вычислены в момент объявления `const VEGETABLE_MESSAGE` и больше меняться не будут. Так сделано чтобы программист мог контролировать что именно и когда будет вычислено. Если вы хотите вычислять одну шаблонную  строку много раз, её надо именно вычислять много раз. Скажем, поместить в функцию, которую вы будете вызывать в момент, когда данные готовы:

```
const vegetableMessage = (vegetableGarden, messageId) => {
    switch (messageId) {
    case 0: return `Clean vegetable garden: ${vegetableGarden.building}%`;
    case 1: return `Seeds planted: ${vegetableGarden.seedPlant} seeds`;
    case 2: return `Collect the harvest: ${vegetableGarden.harvesting} %`;
    case 3: return '<span style="color:red">You forgot to water the seeds, the entire harvest was lost!</span>';
    case 4: return '<span style="color:red">Water seeds: no</span>';
    case 5: return '<span style="color:green">Water seeds: yes</span>';
    }
};

...

document.getElementById('massageVG').innerHTML = vegetableMessage(VEGETABLE_GARDEN, mesID);
```

**P.S.** Я отказался от массива, что бы не вычислять много строк, когда нужна только одна.